# Matlab - Interrupt processus using a handler

Tags: matlab, handler, video-processing

I do video processing and I want to know if it would be possible to put in pause my processus using a keyboard key.

I want to be able to stop the processus by pressing "esc" for example. I want to do some stuff when my processus is on pause like redifine my points of interest (head and tail of a mouse)  by clicking on it on the frame we stopped.

I was thinking to put a condition like :

```
if user press esc
    do some stuff ...
end
```

Is it possible ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and want to share it with you in case somebody ask the same question in the future.

Here is the function I found on MathWorks - File Exchange :

[function to stop a processus by pressing a keyboard key](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8297-getkeywait)

I hope it will help